# Access violation writing location exception while debugging

Tags: c++, windows, service, visual-studio-debugging

I am trying to debug a c++ windows service when the following exception is thrown (only in debug mode, in realse the exception is not thrown):
"Exception thrown at 0x00007FF75127C410 in xxxxxxxx.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000018818AF3000".

Importent note:
the code worked for me before but probably some workspace changes has corrupted it. when it worked i was developing in VS 17 i have recentlly changed the IDE to VS 19. when the problem occured i have tried to go back to VS 17 but it didnt work.

- NOTHING IN THE CODE HAS CHANGE! its the same version as the one that worked before
- I have tried going back to VS 17
- I have tried changing project configuration like "basic runtime checks" or "Runtime Library" because i cant figure out why DEBUG and RELEASE work differently in this scenario

**EDIT:**

```cpp
    USHORT          logFileHeaderVersion;
    DLLS_CHECK_MODE eDllCheckMode;
    LONGLONG        lastClientTimeZValue;
    LONGLONG        lastServerClientTimeDelta;
    wstring         computerName;
    string          macAddresses;
    BYTE*           buffer;
    DWORD           dwBytesToWrite  = 0;
    DWORD           dwBytesWritten  = 0;

    logFileHeaderVersion        = LOG_FILE_HEADER_VERSION;
    eDllCheckMode               = getConfigurationManager()->getDllsCheckMode();
    lastClientTimeZValue        = Globals::getLastClientTimeZValue();
    lastServerClientTimeDelta   = Globals::getLastServerClientTimeDelta();
    computerName                = getComputerName();
    macAddresses                = getMacAddresses();

    // Convert time delta values from ticks to milliseconds.
    lastClientTimeZValue        = lastClientTimeZValue      / MILLISECOND_IN_TICKS;
    lastServerClientTimeDelta   = lastServerClientTimeDelta / MILLISECOND_IN_TICKS;

    // Determine header size.
    dwBytesToWrite  +=  2;                                      // Header-size size.
    dwBytesToWrite  +=  2;                                      // Header version size.
    dwBytesToWrite  +=  1;                                      // Mode size.
    dwBytesToWrite  +=  8;                                      // Client time Z value size.
    dwBytesToWrite  +=  8;                                      // Server client time delta size.
    dwBytesToWrite  +=  (   (computerName.size() + 1) * 2   );  // Computer name size (+ null terminator, wide string).
    dwBytesToWrite  +=  (   macAddresses.size() + 1         );  // Mac addresses size (+ null terminator).

    // Allocate the header.
    buffer = new BYTE[dwBytesToWrite];

    // Fill the header.

    *((USHORT*)     (buffer + dwBytesWritten)) = (USHORT)   dwBytesToWrite;
    dwBytesWritten  +=  2;

    *((USHORT*)     (buffer + dwBytesWritten)) =            logFileHeaderVersion;
    dwBytesWritten += 2;

    *((BYTE*)       (buffer + dwBytesWritten)) = (BYTE)     eDllCheckMode;
    dwBytesWritten  +=  1;

    *((LONGLONG*)   (buffer + dwBytesWritten)) =            lastClientTimeZValue;
    dwBytesWritten  +=  8;

    *((LONGLONG*)   (buffer + dwBytesWritten)) =            lastServerClientTimeDelta;
    dwBytesWritten  +=  8;

    wcscpy_s(   (PWCHAR)(buffer + dwBytesWritten),  dwBytesToWrite - dwBytesWritten,    computerName.c_str());
    dwBytesWritten  +=  (   (computerName.size() + 1) * 2   );
```

The exception is thrown in the following line: i think its something to do with the usage of wstring. and maybe the RELEASE preforming some optimization that fix the problem in the DEBUG

```
    wcscpy_s(   (PWCHAR)(buffer + dwBytesWritten),  dwBytesToWrite - dwBytesWritten,    computerName.c_str());
```

Comment: Probably you have some undefined behavior in your code.

Comment: Is `computerName` a wide string?

Comment: ***i cant figure out why DEBUG and RELEASE work differently in this scenario*** Points to undefined behavior somewhere in your code.

Comment: `buffer + dwBytesWritten` maybe you are exceeding the size of your buffer.

Comment: @drescherjm The code did not change. i have already debugged it before. UB would have happen before if thats the case. am i wrong?
I think the solution will be somewhere in project configuration or maybe VS lib missing or curropted becuase of the IDE changes

Comment: I think you do not understand what "undefined behavior" means.  UB was happening before, you just didn't notice it because it had appeared to work correctly.

Comment: no any ub in your code. exception say that code (you not show it) simply wrong. always wrong. but some time wrong code can by chance executed without exception. anyway you need search error in your code and analyze exception moment

Comment: please provide a [mcve], we can't fix code we cant see